# how to check exist user and pass in mongoCollection for set in session?

Tags: java, mongodb, servlets, mongo-java

what can I write in if() to check the parameters taken from the login form exist in the collection or not?

```
String username = request.getParameter("user");
String password = request.getParameter("pass");
String[] remeberusr = request.getParameterValues("remember");

MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
DB db = client.getDB("mydb");
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("members");
BasicDBObject setquery = new BasicDBObject();
setquery.put("user", username);
setquery.put("pass", password);

DBCursor result = collection.find(setquery);

if (?)) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("user", username);
    session.setAttribute("pass", password);
    session.setAttribute("remember", remeberuser);
    response.sendRedirect("session.jsp");
} else {
    out.print("user and pass incorrected!");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(hasNext())
```

[hasNext()](https://api.mongodb.com/java/2.6/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html#hasNext()) Checks if there is another object available

Answer (score 0):

I have used this method in my past for a MySQL database hope it help just fetch the username and password stored in your DB and check by using for loop and in if use (==) operator